# Compare to sets of files with coroutines in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have written a function that scans files (pictures) from two Lists and check if a file is in both lists.

The code below is working as expected, but for large sets it takes some time. So I tried to do this in parallel with coroutines. But in sets of 100 sample files the programm was always slower than without coroutines.

The code:

```
private fun doJob()  {
    val filesToCompare = File("C:\\Users\\Tobias\\Desktop\\Test").walk().filter { it.isFile }.toList()
    val allFiles = File("\\\\myserver\\Photos\\photo").walk().filter { it.isFile }.toList()

    println("Files to scan: ${filesToCompare.size}")

    filesToCompare.forEach { file ->
        var multipleDuplicate = 0
        var s = "This file is a duplicate"
        s += "\n${file.absolutePath}"
        allFiles.forEach { possibleDuplicate ->
            if (file != possibleDuplicate) { //only needed when both lists are the same
                // Files that have the same name or contains the name, so not every file gets byte comparison
                if (possibleDuplicate.nameWithoutExtension.contains(file.nameWithoutExtension)) {
                    try {
                        if (Files.mismatch(file.toPath(), possibleDuplicate.toPath()) == -1L) {
                            s += "\n${possibleDuplicate.absolutePath}"
                            i++
                            multipleDuplicate++

                            println(s)
                        }
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        println(e.message)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (multipleDuplicate > 1) {
            println("This file has $multipleDuplicate duplicate(s)")
        }
    }

    println("Files scanned: ${filesToCompare.size}")
    println("Total number of duplicates found: $i")
}
```

How have I tried to add the coroutines?

I wrapped the code inside the first forEach in `launch{...}` the idea was that for each file a coroutine starts and the second loop is done concurrently. I expected the program to run faster but in fact it was about the same time or slower.

How can I achieve this code to run in parallel faster?

Comment: Which coroutine scope did you use? And more specifically which dispatcher? If you just used `runBlocking { ... }`, then everything still ran on a single thread, and thus wasn't parallel

Comment: My guess is that in your case IO is a bottleneck, not CPU, so you can't increase the performance by adding concurrency. This is similar when we copy files in a file manager. Starting another copying on the same disk will probably decrease the performance, not increase it.

Comment: Also note that your algorithm has to compare each file with each file, its time complexity is `O(N*M)` which is pretty bad. `nameWithoutExtension` trick probably saves a lot of computing time, but still in many cases you have to read the same file multiple times. I suggest you to create a hash of each file and compare hashes instead of files (optionally, compare files if hashes match). This could increase the performance a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running each inner loop in a coroutine seems to be a decent approach. The problem might lie in the dispatcher you were using. If you used `runBlocking` and `launch` without context argument, you were using a single thread to run all your coroutines.

Since there is mostly blocking IO here, you could instead use `Dispatchers.IO` to launch your coroutines, so your coroutines are dispatched on multiple threads. The parallelism should be automatically limited to 64, but if your memory can't handle that, you can also use `Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(n)` to reduce the number of threads.

Comment: You are right. Without `Dispatchers.IO` it only runs on `main` thread. Thank you very much